# двоеточие или тире в уточнительном предложении

Tags: орфография

Как правильно написать?

Расположение склада - Франция.

Answer (score 1):

Если это просто предложение, то надо – по правилу постановки тире между подлежащим и сказуемым – ставить определённым образом тире: *Расположение склада – Франция.*

Двоеточие возможно в том случае, если даётся перечень чего-либо. (Такое можно обычно, например, в учебниках увидеть.) Например:

*Расположение склада: Франция.*

*Город: Париж.*

*Улица: Les pieuvres du roi.*

*Место прибытия: 14:50 по московскому времени.*